# How to change the ALT+TAB hotkey to something else?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

For example I would like ALT+TAB to work for Numpad Page Down. I have tried with AutoHotkey, but still no luck.

I was also trying with this code:

```
; set Left Windows Key for switching to previous window/app
$LWin::Send !{Tab}
```

The script above is working well. It changes the window when you press the Left Win hotkey

I was trying to change it to:

```
$NumpadPgDn::Send !{Tab}
```

but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you would like Numpad Page Down to do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

It's easy enough to do this using AutoHotkey.

For your given example, you could use:

```
NumpadPgDn:: Send ^!{Tab}
LAlt & Tab:: MsgBox You pressed Alt-Tab
```

I tested it, although on Windows 10, and it worked quite well.

Comment: Hey, i have tested it.. sitll no luck, i run your script and after all when i press Numpad Page Down it shrolls down (for example) this page where i'm writing at the moment

Comment: Might be a differebce between Windows 7 and 10. Try the more explicit : `Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}`.

Comment: That code isn't working, same as before it shrolls down the page after i press PgDn
`NumpadPgDn:: Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up} 
LAlt & Tab:: MsgBox You pressed Alt-Tab`

Comment: Edit: GOT IT
`PgDn:: Send !{Tab}`
This code working properly on Windows 7 :)

Comment: Thanks mate, script above working properly